# Are all public key a result of computing g^k mod p

Tags: encryption, public-key, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

I just read through the text book definition of Diffie–Hellman key exchange. And from what i understand, the public key that is shared based on the protocol is calculated from:

`g^k mod p`

where g is a generator in the multiplicative group, and p is a large prime and k is the private key.

My question is, are all public/private key generated to have this relationship? Or this way of generating the public key from a private key and a `g` and `p` is peculiar to the Diffie–Hellman key exchange construction?

I mean if I want to generate a private key pair for use other than key exchange, for example for encryption, will I use a similar construct or something different?

Comment: It is based on a discrete logarithm. RSA is based on trapdoor permutation, and we have some other in Lattice based. The secret and public key is determined by the underlying problem,

Comment: For encryption you can use a (EC)DH primitive to implement [(EC)IES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme). For signatures there is (EC)DSA that is also derived from the Discrete Logarithm **problem**. However, that doesn't mean that you can use it for **any** particular scheme *and it certainly doesn't mean that other algorithms work in a similar fashion or rely on the same DL-problem*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, are all public/private key generated to have this relationship?

No; DH does that, but there are other public key algorithms do something different.

With RSA [1], the public key is a pair $n, e$, while the private key can be represented as $n$ and a value $d = e^{-1} \bmod \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$ (where $p, q$ are the prime factors of $n$.  As you can see, that's rather different.

Things get even more different when you start looking at postquantum algorithms, such as lattice schemes (e.g. NTRU) or code based schemes (e.g. McEliece).

---

[1]: Actually, it's far more common for questioners to assume that 'all-the-world-is-RSA'; it's rather refreshing to hear from another viewpoint...